# How to write the drop down menu logic in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a Drop down box Based on the selection i should populate the content specific to that year. At any time i can only populate one year content and i need to hide the rest of content based on the selection. How should i code this using Jquery

```
<div style="margin:4px 0 0 0;">
          <label> Select Year </label>
            <select name="select_Release">
                <option value="2011">2011</option>
                <option value="2010">2010</option>
                <option value="2009">2009</option>
                <option value="2008">2008</option>
                <option value="2007">2007</option>
                <option value="2006">2006</option>
                <option value="2005">2005</option>
            </select>
      </div>

<div>Some 2011 content  to display</div>
<div>Some 2010 content  to display</div>
<div>Some 2009 content  to display</div>
<div>Some 2008 content  to display</div>
<div>Some 2007 content  to display</div>
<div>Some 2006 content  to display</div>
<div>Some 2005 content  to display</div>
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand what you need. You want to select a year on the select_Release and show the corresponding div?

Comment: @Guilherme Costa YEs that what i need. I want to display the content based on the selection. So when I show content based on the year selection rest  of the content should be  hidden

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/FDpmb/1/

**jQuery**:

```
//traverse the DOM once to get all of your div tags per year
var years = $('.options > div')
//define a function that will show/hide the year content
var check = function($select)
{
    var year = $select.val();
    years.hide();
    $('div[data-year="' + year + '"]').show();
}
//get the instance of your select box
var element = $('#select_Release');
//bind an event handler
element.change(function () { check($(this)); });
//and we want to show the correct content initially, so call our change function
check(element);
```

Slightly modified markup (Note the `id` on your select box, and the extra `div` tag and `data-year` attributes):

```
<div style="margin:4px 0 0 0;">
    <label> Select Year </label>
    <select id="select_Release" name="select_Release">
        <option value="2011">2011</option>
        <option value="2010">2010</option>
        <option value="2009">2009</option>
        <option value="2008">2008</option>
        <option value="2007">2007</option>
        <option value="2006">2006</option>
        <option value="2005">2005</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="options">
    <div data-year="2011">Some 2011 content  to display</div>
    <div data-year="2010">Some 2010 content  to display</div>
    <div data-year="2009">Some 2009 content  to display</div>
    <div data-year="2008">Some 2008 content  to display</div>
    <div data-year="2007">Some 2007 content  to display</div>
    <div data-year="2006">Some 2006 content  to display</div>
    <div data-year="2005">Some 2005 content  to display</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be kind of a pain to get all of the actions for a custom dropdown working correctly. I would recommend checking out https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui/wiki/Selectmenu

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
<div class="years">
    <div>Some 2011 content  to display</div>
    <div>Some 2010 content  to display</div>
    <div>Some 2009 content  to display</div>
    <div>Some 2008 content  to display</div>
    <div>Some 2007 content  to display</div>
    <div>Some 2006 content  to display</div>
    <div>Some 2005 content  to display</div>
</div>
```

and at your CSS file:

> .years div { display: none; }

then at your jquery:

```
$('select[name="select_Release"]').change(function(){
    $('.years div').hide();
    $('.years div:contains("' + $(this).val() + '")').show();
});
```